# match two different column from two different tables

Tags: mysql

i have two tables: table1 and table2 using database mysql.

Fields of table1: usrnm1, ques1
Fields of table2: usrnm2, ques2

Data of table1: abc, xyz
Data of table2: pqr, def

In html form, i am taking username from the user.
I want to retrieve corresponding ques in other input tag.

How can i check the input(by user) in both these tables and retrieving corresponding ques.

I want these type of output:
If user enter abc then i want xyz as output. 
And if user enter pqr then i want def as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine 2 table if you rename the fields so that they match.

So you can either do it like this:

```
(SELECT usrnm1 as usrnm, ques1 as ques FROM table1 WHERE usrnm1 = "abc")
UNION
(SELECT usrnm2 as usrnm, ques2 as ques FROM table2 WHERE usrnm2 = "abc");
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT usrnm1 as usrnm, ques1 as ques FROM table1)
  UNION
  (SELECT usrnm2 as usrnm, ques2 as ques FROM table2)
) a WHERE usrnm = "abc";
```